# Using Plotly with Angular

Tags: angular, plotly

I have a simple Angular project to learn how to use Plotly with latest Angular. Running ng serve shows this:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2020-08-11T20:30:09.702Z
Hash: 4d3096aeaa7aa502b570
Time: 5526ms
chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 285 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 93.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 3.26 MB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 329 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/angular-plotly.js/src/app/plotly-via-cdn/plotly-via-cdn.module.d.ts(9,16): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/angular-plotly.js/src/app/plotly-via-cdn/plotly-via-cdn.module.d.ts(10,16): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/angular-plotly.js/src/app/shared/plotly.service.d.ts(11,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

Failed to compile.
```

App module:

```
import { PlotlyModule } from 'angular-plotly.js';
PlotlyModule.plotlyjs = PlotlyJS;
```

Tried both PlotlyViaWindowModule and PlotlyViaCDNModule, same.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/issues/104)?

Comment: I see now :). Thanks. Will check it out.